# Battery changed receiver not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to react to the charging state in my app.

I registered the receiver for it in onCreate()

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

the receiver looks like that:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        plugged= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED,0);
        String test = Integer.valueOf(plugged).toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), test,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

but even if the device is plugged in the plugged variable is 0. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS. The BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED can be used if you want more details about the type of power source I believe.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent intentResult = registerReceiver(null, filter);

int state = intentResult.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);

switch (state) {
    case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
    case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL:
        //charging
        break;
    default:
        //not charging
}
```